# How to better write code for extracting raster data in R. Maybe a loop?

Tags: r, r-raster, rgdal

I am still getting my feet wet with R. I have an idea to migrate some ArcView functions into R with the following scripts. I would love to be able to have my df help fill in. Would I go about this by writing long pipes for each of the metrics I am concerned with at the bottom (range, avg1, avg2) then running it through a loop? There isn't a point in making my dumby data since I have no dumby raster data available.

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(raster)

df <- data.frame(location = paste('location', 1:4), 
             latitude = c(35.123+(1:4)), longitude = c(-120.123+(1:4)))
```

#steps create shapefiles

#load raster data

```
a <- raster(x= 'data/raster/a.tif')#datum=NAD83
b <- raster(x= 'data/raster/b.tif')#datum=NAD83
c <- raster(x= 'data/raster/c.tif')#datum=NAD83
```

#extract from

```
location1_ws_a <- raster::extract(a,location, df= TRUE)
location1_ws_b <- raster::extract(b,location, df= TRUE)
location1_ws_c <- raster::extract(c,location, df= TRUE)

range <- max(location1_ws_b)-min(location1_ws_b)
avg1 <- mean(location1$a)
avg2 <- mean(location1$c)

output <- data.frame(location,
                 range,
                 avg1,
                 avg2)
```

In the end I would like a table that has columns name c(location, range, avg1, avg2) with rows location1, location2, location3 and their results
Many Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can include raster data in your example

```
library(raster)
df <- data.frame(location = paste('location', 1:4), 
             latitude = c(35.123+(1:4)), longitude = c(-120.123+(1:4)))
             
r <- raster(ymn=36, ymx=40, xmn=-120, xmx=-116, nrow=100, ncol=100)
set.seed(0)
a <- setValues(r, sample(ncell(r)))
b <- setValues(r, sample(ncell(r)))
c <- setValues(r, sample(ncell(r)))
s <- stack(a, b, d)
names(s) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

Use extract. NOTE that the order is longitude/latitude, and that in your example data these are reversed. Hence the use of `df[,3:2]` to correct this.

```
e <- extract(s, df[,3:2])
```

And bind

```
out <- cbind(df, e)
out

#    location latitude longitude    a    b    c
#1 location 1   36.123  -119.123 3276 3575 5866
#2 location 2   37.123  -118.123 6785 4712 2944
#3 location 3   38.123  -117.123 9586 7439 7887
#4 location 4   39.123  -116.123 5874 9826 3570
```

From here on out I am not quite sure what you want. Perhaps the below?

```
out$avg1 <- mean(out$a)
out$avg2 <- mean(out$c)
out$range <- max(out$b) - min(out$b)
```